# OperatingSystemMXBean CPU usage methods

Tags: java, jmx

I'm using the Oracle JDK 7 on RHEL

Does the method `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad()` return percentage CPU usage across all available cpus on the machine?

Also, when I used `java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemLoadAverage()` it returned 8.89. My machine only has 8 cpus. That's 889% CPU usage?? But isn't 800% max since I only have 8 cpus?

Answer (score 0):

The load average is the number of waiting threads on average.  The upper limit is based on the number of threads you have (not the number of CPUs)

Comment: Any idea how this is calculated? Just trying to figure out what's a healthy getSystemLoadAverage() percentage for my machine.

Also re my first question. Is getSystemCpuLoad() percentage for all 8 cpus

Comment: The OS samples the number of waiting threads and averages it over 1 minutes, 5 minutes and 15 minutes.  How healthy this is depends on the number of CPUs you have and the impact this has on your application. e.g. in a trading system, a load of 1 is bad. In a batch processing system 100 might be bad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have max of 800% and it's completely occupied + you have 89% processes  waiting for cpu slice. This indicates your system is overloaded.